# Add validation to HTML5 required fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using HTML5's `required` attribute on my input elements and select boxes and PHP for validation.

How can I show an alert if the `required` fields are not filled in? I tried using `onsubmit()` but the form is processed anyway and no alert is shown.

Comment: Please show us your code, ideally in a jsFiddle. We can hardly debug code if we don't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user's browser supports html5, he cant submit the form if not all the required fields have been written into.

Generally, you can prevent a form from submitting in jQuery like so:

```
$('#yourformselector').submit(function(event) {
    $(this).find('[required="required"]').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).val().length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a modern/newer web browser, your default browser alerts should automatically display.

Or try:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var incomplete = $('form :input').filter(function() {
                             return $(this).val() == '';
                         });
        //if incomplete contains any elements, the form has not been filled 
        if(incomplete.length) {
            alert('please fill out the form');
            //to prevent submission of the form
            return false;
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: i am only want to check that element which contain only 'required' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You may use checkValidity(), it will try to validate with attributes like pattern, min, max, required, etc.  [Follow this link to go deeper here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation)

```js
function myFunction() {
    var inpObj = document.getElementById("id1");
    if (inpObj.checkValidity() == false) {
        alert('invalid input')
    } else {
        alert('valid input')
    } 
}
```

```html
<input id="id1" type="number" min="100" max="300" required>
<button onclick="myFunction()">OK</button>
```